# Console (not X/Wayland) screen blanker ineffective under Bookworm?

Tags: terminal, power-management, screenblank

Note that I am **not running X or Wayland**. This is about the hardware text console.

I have a pair of Pi 400s with HDMI connected monitors.

If I add consoleblank=300 to cmdline.txt, what happens is that after 5 minutes the cursor disappears, but the screen stays on and the text stays there.

Does this just not work under the bookworm kernel? Is there an alternative that actually works - that is, causes the monitor to enter a power-save state?

Comment: I've read that *adding `vc4.force_hotplug=3` to end of command in /boot/cmdline.txt* solves the problem - apparently it's monitor specific - some monitors don't behave like they should which turns the screen back on because the pi thinks the monitor has been unplugged and plugged in (by the way, the value 3 means both displays, you can also use 1 for hdmi1 and 2 for hdmi2)

Comment: That seems to have worked! If you turn that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You might also find the [`cec-utils` package](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberrypi-hdmi-cec/) offers some solutions

Comment: These are specifically monitors rather than televisions. While it's possible that they respond to CEC, I would be more inclined to believe they were designed for the older i2c signaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read that adding `vc4.force_hotplug=3` to end of command in `/boot/cmdline.txt` solves the problem - [source](https://github.com/raspberrypi/bookworm-feedback/issues/67#issuecomment-1773841184)

The value 3 means both displays, you can also use 1 for hdmi1 only and 2 for hdmi2 only

Apparently it's monitor specific - some monitors don't behave like they should. The theory is that when the screen is "blanked", the monitor toggles `hotplug` which makes the pi think the monitor has been unplugged and plugged in.